# Can I block same origin request using CORS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, nestjs

As weird as the title sounds, But, is it possible that I use CORS to somehow deny same-origin request?

For example my web page is served from same server+port. Both FE and BE are say http://localhost:3000

Comment: *"my API server is hosted at localhost:3000, but I wanna block requests from say a localhost:4200 webpage"* - That's a different origin.  CORS already applies in that scenario.  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Can you elaborate?  What specifically isn't working in what specific code that you have?

Comment: in most browsers, localhost is a special case, you can ignore CORS / https-only features as it would hinder development.

Comment: a mistake i realised. i was not sending the request from localhost:4200. I'm actualling calling the API endpoint directly from the browser URL.

Comment: @yellowsir so you're saying that browsers' behaviour towards CORS on localhost (with different ports) are inconsistent, therefore should be ignored.

Comment: i'm saying you should test your final solution with a real domain name.
Also note, CORS are implemented by the Browser and thus, one can always skip them. So if you want to restirct access, you need some server-side solution..

Comment: @zhuhang.jasper: Are you saying that you specifically want to deny requests from the *same origin* but allow requests from *other origins*?  Why?

Comment: *my API server is hosted at `localhost:3000`, but I wanna block requests coming from browser that directly has `localhost:3000` at the URL* - why would you need that? This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: CORS does not block anything, the SOP does. On the contrary: CORS's goal is to relax the SOP's restrictions on cross-origin access.

Comment: @jub0bs can you post it as an answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

**CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is designed to control cross-origin requests, not same-origin requests**.

You'll need to use a different approach. You can achieve the desired behavior by implementing custom middleware to block requests based on the referer header (or other conditions).

Let's say block requests from `localhost:3000` :

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class SameOriginBlockMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const referer = req.header('Referer') || req.header('Origin');
    if (referer && referer.startsWith('http://localhost:3000')) {
      res.status(403).json({ message: 'Same-origin requests are not allowed' });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

```
// src/app.module.ts
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SameOriginBlockMiddleware } from './same-origin-block.middleware';

@Module({
  // ...
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(SameOriginBlockMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

#### Update :

Another solution is to require an API key :

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const apiKey = req.headers['x-api-key'];
    if (!apiKey || apiKey !== 'your-api-key') {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' });
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt. in short, your answer is NO, cors cannot block same origin. BTW, I've revised my question as i made a mistake on the 4200 example. As port 4200 should be different origin from 3000, my CORS config should block it.

Comment: One possible solution is to require an API key or use a specific custom header for all API requests.